# How to use an Active X textbox search bar in an Excell 365 protected worksheet?

Tags: excel, activex

I've made an excel database, in which i put an active X TextBox (search box) to retrieve information. When i protected the worksheet, and try to use the search box, it shows the message: Run Time 1004 "You cannot use this command on a protected sheet. To use this command, you must first unprotect the sheet..."

How it could be used even when the spread is protected?

I'd use macros for the funtionality of the database sheet, but dont know what code, if so, its necesary to use with.

Comment: You have to set then locked-property to false in the "format control" dialog

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.